# If my Yahoo mail is unused for years, will someone be able to register my previous mail address?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I signed for Yahoo mail, and made a Facebook account using it years ago. I suffered a head injury, which made my memory really bad. Now, I have no way of remembering that email address, and that FB has been deactivated for years. Could someone possibly reclaim my old email address, and then use it to access my old FB? Thanks

Comment: I can’t find an official help page, so I will not post it as an answer, but yes, someone **can** reclaim your old email address if it was not used for years and theoretically could access your old Facebook account.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Apparently, Yahoo and Facebook have developed a way to avoid this. I'm not sure, though. https://www.computerworld.com/article/2838283/facebook-yahoo-prevent-use-of-recycled-email-addresses-to-hijack-accounts.html

Comment: PS how can I get more answers for this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if your account has not been used for years and has this `yahoo.com` extension, it may be available for use by new users.

https://help.yahoo.com/kb/yahoo-email-site-sln15136.html

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]! This answer would be a lot better if you could [edit] in some references to support this.